# How many fields are there in most flux compactifications?

Tags: resource-recommendations, compactification, string-theory-landscape

[Quoting from this paper](https://doi.org/10.3390/universe5070176):

> At first sight, the most striking thing about these compactifications is how many fields they have compared to the Standard Model. While the particle physicists of the 1930s were surprised by the muon, asking “Who ordered that?”, string theorists should be even more surprised by the thousands or even hundreds of thousands of fields in the most complex compactifications. Still, this is not in contradiction with observation as these fields will be light only in the most symmetric compactifications; symmetry breaking can give large masses to almost all of these fields. Others could be in hidden sectors, coupling only gravitationally to the Standard Model and to the inflaton, so that they are not produced in reheating. While there are also compactifications with relatively few fields, certainly we should look for evidence of many fields in our universe.

Unfortunately, the author doesn't cite any papers for the claim that there are thousands or hundreds of thousands of fields in the most complex compactifications.

Two questions:

- Any references for thousands and/or hundreds of thousands of fields?
- What number of fields are most typical (or favored)?